# React native form

Tags: forms, react-native

I'm very new to react-native and I'm having trouble of what things to use.
I'm building an app in which I need to login or register. For now I just want to use a form, when I fill it submits datas to my api and get logged. I don't know what kind of form component I should use, there seem to be different component to install and use, I need some advice 'cause I'm a little bit lost.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Elaborate about the actual question. If this is only a question about opinion of different libraries for React Native, then it's not part of the SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/) along with [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements) or [nativebase](https://nativebase.io/)

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer ! I'm gonna try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tcomb-form-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcomb-form-native).It simplifies creating a form.

Answer (score 0):

Well to code it from scratch you need 2 textInput one for the username or email and the other for password and a button  or touchableOpacity for Login or signUp button. and authfunction which is the function to certify the credentials. In your APP file you check wether the user is authenticated or no and display the next screen you can use redux to pass data around but I will make it simple here and use AsyncStorage  to Authenticate the user let me know if you need it.

import React,{Component,useState} from ‘react’;
 import {TextInput,Text,SafeAreaView,StyleSheet, Button} from ‘react-native’
 export default function Login = () => {               [username,setUsername]=useState();
       [password,setPassword]=useState();
   return(
        
                setUsername(val)} />
                  setPassword(val)} />
                   authfunction(username,password)} />
        
  );
}